# Google Cloud SQL - OS environment not set to Google App Engine

Tags: python, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am attempting to connected to a Google Cloud SQL instance in python and have gone through google's tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/

I am essentially cloning google's tutorial code and for some reason this line isn't working right for me:

```
if (os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE') and
  os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE').startswith('Google App Engine/')):
```

This if statement is not being entered and I'm not sure why - it is then defaulting to accessing a local database based on the else statement. How is the os server_software environment set? I'm new to all of this but basically because that is not getting set, I am not able to access my google cloud sql instance. How do I make sure this if statement is entered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SERVER_SOFTWARE` is an environment variable that is automatically set by GAE. It could either be something like `Google App Engine/x.x.xx` when deployed or `Development/x.x` when running locally.

Basically the section of the code you're referring to checks whether your app is deployed and is running on GAE servers and if so - it will connect to a Google Cloud SQL instance, otherwise, if your app is running locally, it will attempt to connect to a local mysql instance.

It's done that way because you wouldn't normally want to mess with your production (deployed) data while developing & testing locally as many thing could go wrong.

Since you're stating that the if statement is not being entered - it's safe to assume that you are trying to run the program locally but are expecting it to connect to a Google Cloud SQL instance, for that, the next few lines in the example you provided are explaining how to do it:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, db='guestbook', user='root', charset='utf8')
# Alternatively, connect to a Google Cloud SQL instance using:
# db = MySQLdb.connect(host='ip-address-of-google-cloud-sql-instance', port=3306, user='root', charset='utf8')
```

so what you need to do is comment out the first line (the one it attempts to connect to a localhost mysql server) and uncomment the one where it connects to the Google Cloud SQL instance (note that you will have to update several parameters that reflect the configuration that you have, i.e. the `host` parameter and possible others).

Comment: Is there a reason I would want or not want the app deployed? Is that just basically for whether other people can access it?

Comment: @iOSBeginner the [Development Server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver?hl=en) is used for developing & testing your app, you wouldn't want to use it in production for other people to use. So yes, it's about other people being able to access it + there are some limitations that you will run into when develop only locally. If you are not indending to deploy your app then you probably don't need to stick to GAE att all as the actual benefits & cool features are on Google's servers, not on your local machine.